# How to reach my IOT device from everywhere without static IP

Tags: networking, ip, lan, iot

I am able to access to my IOT device if I assign it a static IP with a service like dydns. But I would like to be able to reach it without relying on something.

I was thinking that my IOT device could ,on every start, write in a database its IP adress so my script on the server knows its ip.

The problem is that the IP will correspond to my hotspot IP. I am missing the connection part "hotspot -->IOT device".

For example I would like to be able to connect my IOT device to my mobile phone in hotspot mode.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to re-design your system: if when it comes online the IoT device always connects (and stays connected) to a server component (which has a well-known/unchanging hostname/IP address), then the server can always send the IoT device a command over that TCP connection without knowing the hostname/IP address of the IoT device, and without it having to be contactable from the internet, i.e. this approach is firewall-friendly at the device end.

This is how the IoT is architected when using e.g. MQTT: devices connect inwards to the MQTT broker (i.e. server). MQTT also removes the need for the server application itself to need to connect to the clients. MQTT uses a concept called publish/subscribe with pre-agreed 'topics' - the client will subscribe to a 'command' topic, the server app publishes commands to that topic and the broker handles forwarding the command to the device. Incoming data from the device is published to another topic and the server application subscribes to that topic, the broker forwards the published data. You can try pub/sub example (using a browser, but real devices can also connect to the same server) using e.g. http://m2m.demos.ibm.com/utilities.html

Comment: Should I look for MQTT to be able to connect the IOT device to a server? ( I mean the stays connected part)

Comment: Yes you can do that, obviously. You could also as a short-term solution use the public mqtt server, your device connects to that and subscribes to your chosen command topic. then in your web server you can use e.g. paho browser/javascript client to publish to the command topic.There are other more homegrown ways for handling a single device but as soon as you want to scale up these will get more complex. If all you ever want is a single device then a simple python socket server will probably suffice, make your web server connect to that to send a message. HTH Barny